# Declared variable within a switch block

Tags: c, scope, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int expr = 0;

        switch (expr)
        {
                int i;

                case 0:
                        i = 17;
                default:
                        printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

In the above code, variable `i` declared within the switch case block and print into default case. Use following command to compiled in GCC compiler on linux platform.

```
gcc -Wall switch.c
```

and it is print correct output.

So, **is it defined behavior or undefined behavior?**

Comment: It is UB because it will access unintialized value if expr is not 0. But in this case, no

Comment: OK, forgot to ask, why did you think this would be undefined behaviour? Reason?

Comment: Using a variable before it has been initialized is undefined behaviour. The fact that it has been declared in the switch block rather than outside the switch block doesn't matter.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I thought inside the switch statement, without any casses declared variable not execute.

Comment: See [6.8.4.2 The switch statement p7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Ah, was just updating the same, to add to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**In this case**, it is not undefined behaviour.

For `case 0` (when `expr == 0`, which is your case), `i` gets assigned a value before being *used* (value being read from).

---

OK, to elaborate a bit more, for the snippet

```
switch (expr)
    {
            int i;

            case 0:
                    i = 17;
            default:
                    printf("%d\n", i);
    }
```

just makes the variable `i` defined in the block scope. Even if, the code would have been written as

```
            int i = 0; //or any value
```

the value of `i` not initialized, it's just the identifier is visible in the scope. You must have another statement assigning value to `i` before you can make use of it.

In this regard, the `C11` standard has a very enlightening example and description. let me quote it, from chapter §6.8.4.2/P7

> EXAMPLE In the artificial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
> int i = 4;
> f(i);
> case 0:
> i = 17;
> /* falls through into default code */
> default:
> printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> **the object whose identifier is ``i exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but is never initialized,** and thus if
>   the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the printf
>   function will access an indeterminate value. [....]